# Can't access index.php by accessing its directoy while calling the exact path is working

Tags: apache, nginx, passenger, plesk

When I try to access folder/index.php by domain.com/folder I always get this error from Phusion Passenger.[image]

Domain.com/folder/index.php works perfectly fine tho. I added index.html and index.php as index files in plesks settings rather than having it on default and also tried everything to find the logs but there are none. Or at least not where they should be.
domain.com btw also works and gives me the main index.html.

What exactly am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, that the base directory for the website should not be in a subfolder like /httpdocs/stupidfolder/...
Everything works fine if you put it directly into httpdocs